# Replace/Remove inner quote in a python string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string:

```
"""
{
   "description":"123456 asdad asa "0-asd;'asddf1231" "12"  ",
   "sale":12
} 
"""
```

I want to decode this into JSON, but the description field is ill-formatted. I am thinking about using `re.sub` to remove all of the inner quotes from the description field, but I've had no luck so far. Does anyone have a good regex hint? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have more data, otherwise you could do it manually. We need more data to be able to tell how sophisticated the cleanup code has to be. For this particular string, you could just replace all instances of quoted numbers with just the numbers, but I don't know if that'll work for all your data.

Comment: yes, production data is wayyyy more complicated.

Comment: Is `"description"` always the first key? Starting from `"desc`, is the relevant text always going to start with `"description":"`? Is it always going to end with `",`? Is it always on it's own line?

Comment: You can assume "description":" never change and ends with ","

Comment: I think I will just end up writing a function to parse this manually.

Comment: And is it always on it's own line?

Comment: Also, do you want to remove just the double-quotes, or also the single-quotes? Or do you just want to replace the double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can try* this, but there should be a better way.

```
(?:.*?(?={))|(?:(?<=}).*)|(?:(?<!:)"(?!,))
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/rF8nV7/2)

Answer (score 0):

I'll just answer this now in case it actually works for you; if it doesn’t, I'll modify this answer.

```
>>> import json
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s =  """ { "description":"123456 asdad asa "0" "12" ", "sale":12 } """
>>>
>>> new_s = re.sub('"(\d+)"', r'\1', s)
>>> new_s
' { "description":"123456 asdad asa 0 12 ", "sale":12 } '
>>>
>>> d = json.loads(new_s)
>>> d
{u'description': u'123456 asdad asa 0 12 ', u'sale': 12}
```